# Why is the text from my text file in Azure blob storage not formatted correctly when downloaded?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

...............................................................................

**Update:**

With guidance from the comments below, I figured out that what I was looking at in the debugger was actually proper JSON. However, the text being returned from the blob was not the full text - it was missing a small percentage of the characters at the end of the file.

I am using JsonConvert to create this text file, which ends up as a serialized version of a ViewModel in the form of JSON.

What I ultimately did that fixed the problem of the missing text, was change how the text was being uploaded to the Blob. I changed the code from this:

```
Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

textWriter.WriteLine(serializedViewModel);

memoryStream.Position = 0;

blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
```

To this

```
var options = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
};

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(serializedViewModel), false))
{
    blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream, null, options);
}
```

I don't understand exactly why the first method didn't work, but the full text now gets uploaded to the blob, and is able to downloaded and used.

................................................................................

When I upload something like this as a text file (which I can manually download from the Storage Explorer and view in Notepad as a .txt file)...

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "ReportBuilderModel": null,
  "ReportBuilderModelId": 0,
  "ReportSections": [
 {
  "$id": "2",
  "ReportSectionModel": {
    "$id": "3",
    "SectionFile": null,
    "Id": 1182,
    "ReportBuilderModelId": 36,
    "SectionName": "Issue Summary",
    "SectionType": 6,
    "Position": 0,
    "ParentSectionId": null,
    "TimeOfReport": "2018-07-28T04:56:38.93",
  }
}
```

...using this code...

```
Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

textWriter.WriteLine(serializedViewModel);

// Get container reference.
blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerReference");

// Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
blobContainer .CreateIfNotExists();

memoryStream.Position = 0;

blockBlob = textFileContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("containerReference");

blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
```

...and when downloading the file from Blob Storage using this code...

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);

    string serializedData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

...serializedData looks like this...

"{\r\n  \"$id\": \"1\",\r\n  \"ReportBuilderModel\": null,\r\n \"ReportBuilderModelId\": 0,\r\n  \"ReportSections\": [\r\n {\r\n      \"$id\": \"2\",\r\n      \"ReportSectionModel\": {\r\n     \"$id\": \"3\",\r\n        \"SectionFile\": null,\r\n    ...

Please help.

Comment: where are you seeing that - perhaps if in the debugger, thats expected

Comment: Yes, in the debugger.

Comment: Use the json viewer

Comment: I'm seeing now that the main problem here is a misunderstanding on my part of what's happening. Using the json viewer in the debugger, the text from the blob is right. Now I just need to figure out how get it formatted correctly to use it for what I'm doing (JsonConvert to serialize models).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes some characters need to be escaped which is why your JSON file looks as it is now. In your case the quotation marks (") within the JSON-string are the characters which need to be escaped.

If the formatting really matters for you, you can simply replace the unneccessary characters like ...

```
string str = "{\r\n \"$id\": \"1\",\r\n \"ReportBuilderModel\": null,\r\n \"ReportBuilderModelId\": 0,\r\n \"ReportSections\": [\r\n {\r\n \"$id\": \"2\",\r\n \"ReportSectionModel\": {\r\n \"$id\": \"3\",\r\n \"SectionFile\": null,\r\n ...";
str = str.Replace("\"", "");
```

If you want to get rid of the `line feed` and `carriage return` too, you can do it just like before:

```
str = str.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

After that the value of `str` is:

```
"{ $id: 1, ReportBuilderModel: null, ReportBuilderModelId: 0, ReportSections: [ { $id: 2, ReportSectionModel: { $id: 3, SectionFile: null, ..."
```

> In computing and telecommunication, an escape character is a character
> which invokes an alternative interpretation on subsequent characters
> in a character sequence. An escape character is a particular case of
> metacharacters. Generally, the judgment of whether something is an
> escape character or not depends on context.
>
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character